# Stacked horizontal waterfall diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-chart, waterfall

Which packages are preferable for making stacked horizontal waterfall diagrams?
A diagram like this:

[image]

The data for this plot is given by

```
x <- data.frame(time = c(rep("this month",3),rep("last month",3)),class = rep(c("Part A","Part B", "Part C"),2),value = c(40,30,45,2,10,-5))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search showed there are several ways of achieving it.
 1. GGPLOT2   (http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/ggplot2-wires.pdf) (page 3)
 2. waterfall package. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waterfall/waterfall.pdf)
 3. Plot.ly https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/  (scroll to the bottom)

Some more examples:  https://www.r-bloggers.com/waterfall-charts-in-style-of-the-economist-with-r/

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(waterfall)
data(rasiel) # Example data of the waterfall package
rasiel
#    label          value   subtotal
# 1  Net Sales       150    EBIT
# 2  Expenses       -170    EBIT 
# 3  Interest         18    Net Income
# 4  Gains            10    Net Income
# 5  Taxes            -2    Net Income

asTheEconomist(
               waterfallchart(value ~ label, data=rasiel,
                              groups=subtotal, main="P&L")
               )
```

[image]
https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/ggplot2-waterfall-charts/

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a link-only answer. These are deprecated in SO.